# Django csrf verification fails after switching off https

Tags: django, nginx, django-csrf

I am using Django 1.7.1 , I made a single change outside of my django web app , i.e switched off https inside nginx since my django webapp moved within the company firewall.

I made no other changes to the webapp , like in any of the django code: I am testing the webapp access via the company vpn.

The home page , which is a form loads fine when I go to http://mywebapp.mycompany.com. 
Now , When I hit submit. I see the CSRF verification failure with a reference to https://mywebapp.mycompany.com! as detailed below. I even get the error in incognito mode to rule out any old cache issues.

I wanted to know the source of the error and feel it is outside of my webapp and within some vpn configuration/ browser cache / some other cache.
I  have checked the possible reasons for CSRF failure given in the django message , and am not doing any of those "bad" things.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this. I want to know whether this is a VPN config problem , an nginx config problem or a django "best practices" problem.

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help
Reason given for failure:
    Referer checking failed - http://mywebapp.mycompany.com/ does not match https://mywebapp.mycompany.com/.

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:
Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
You're seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.
You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
```

I am not doing any of these. My form uses :

```
<form role="form" action={% url "sequence_input" %} data-persist="garlic" data-destroy="false" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
```

The calls to the form are using RequestContext:

```
return render(request,'sequence_input_form.html',{'form':form})
```

And I have the following context processors:

```
            TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS= ("django.core.context_processors.static",
                                          "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                                          "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                                          "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                                          "django.core.context_processors.media",
                                          "django.core.context_processors.tz",
                              "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"django.core.context_processors.request",)
```

My Nginx conf indicating commented lines.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    #listen 443 default ssl;
    charset     utf-8;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name [my server ip];
    #if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
    #   rewrite     ^(.*)   https://$server_name$1 permanent;
    #}
    #if ( $scheme = "http" ) {
    #return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    #}
    #ssl_certificate /home/mywebapp/mywebapp/mywebapp_cert.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key /home/mywebapp/mywebapp/mywebapp_key.key;
    #ssl_certificate_key /home/mywebapp/mywebapp/harijay/mywebapp_webhop_org.key;

    location / {

        uwsgi_pass  django;
            include     /home/mywebapp/mywebapp/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 60000;

        root /home/mywebapp/mywebapp;
        #index pam_lister/templates/sequence_input_form.html;

        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

        location /static {
            autoindex on;
            alias /home/mywebapp/mywebapp/static/;
        }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the `django.core.context_processors.request` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Comment: @aamir adnan : I added that in and am still getting identical error. Will edit question to show that I added that in

Comment: Have you checked that the form is being submitted to http in chrome console? What happens when you go to https url of the form, is it 404?

Comment: I checked with chrome console and network monitoring tab and it clearly indicates a POST to http://mywebapp.mycompany.com and the 403 status. The headers from the console indicate "POST / HTTP/1.1" and a csrf_token and an "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" does that have something to do with it?

Comment: Do you have any of the following in your `settings.py`? `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` or `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True` or `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True` If so, this could be the cause. Also, if your site is redirecting you to https even after you've disabled https, it might be a HSTS header persisting.